# How To Make A .ini File Secure When Reading To It From PHP

Tags: php, mysql, linux, security

I'm creating a website that uses php and mysql. I keep all my mysql access data in a ini file called "config.ini". This file needs to be secure so malicious users cannot get access to mysql access data. The problem occors when a php tries to access it as it access it as the user "www-data" which is not a root user is denies the request. If I then allow permission to "www-data" via the this command.

```
sudo chown -R root:www-data config.ini
sudo chmod -R g+s config.ini
```

Any user can view it by typing in the website address and /config.ini as apache accesses it through the same user, NOT SECURE.

PHP CODE

```
$conf = parse_ini_file('config.ini');
$conn = mysqli_connect($conf["host"], $conf["user"], $conf["password"], $conf["database"]);
```

Any suggestions welcome and in advance thank you.

FULL ANSWER

1)Place config.ini under a directory that is outside the webroot.
2)Create a group with "www-data" in it using this command.

```
sudo chown root:www-data config.ini
```

3) Give it access to read using this command.

```
sudo chmod 640 config.ini
```

4)Access it normally in php but use ../ to direct to the new location.

Comment: Why you don't use `.php` file?

Comment: Move the file to a non web accessible directory.

Comment: `.ini` files aren't really a thing anymore. They used to be under the assumption that generic configuration editors would emerge. They never did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're concerned about malicious access, which of course is a good thing to be concerned about, make sure your `.ini` file is not in any directory that your web server is configured to serve from. That is, make absolutely sure this is outside the web-root of your site.

Secondly, you can usually configure your web server to refuse to serve `.ini` files. You'll also want to ensure that things like directory indexes are turned off so people can't poke around.

Comment: Tankyou but how would I gain access to it.

Comment: @JosephSaunders you can access any file on the file system with php as long as the file permissions allow it. Instead of `parse_ini('config.ini')` just `parse_ini('../config.ini')`

Comment: @JeffLambert That's roughly what I was trying to say, but your example is a lot more specific. Thanks.